# What are Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz’s view of monads

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I've found basic definitions like those found in the comments, too. However I also found rather confusing properties of monads, like they where "living mirrors of the universe" and can be sleeping or awake. So is the idea really that those monads (of which I think like "atoms") are like "minds" or living beings?

Is there a notion of time / order of actions / cause associated with monads?

Comment: Adapting shane's famous line: this question is too broad because we aren't here to do your homework. That mostly as a joke. If this is indeed homework, tag it as such. If not, explain what you have found out so far. Have you gone through the primary sources, [this](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz/#MetLeiIde) sep article?

Comment: Its also worth saying why you're interested. Its such an outre work I'm suprised and intrigued that you are. Are you interested in onads cominf from a Com Sci perspective? In which case Lienbiz won't be helpful at all. His intent is metaphysics.

Answer (score 2):

*Monads* are *individuals*, in a metaphysical sense; thus, they are **not** like *atoms* of modern physics.

From [Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Wilhelm_Leibniz) :

> Leibniz's best known contribution to metaphysics is his theory of monads, as exposited in *Monadologie*. According to Leibniz, monads are elementary particles with blurred perceptions of one another. Monads can also be compared to the corpuscles of the Mechanical Philosophy of René Descartes and others.
>
> *Monads are the ultimate elements of the universe*.
>
> The monads are "substantial forms of being" with the following properties: they are eternal, indecomposable, individual, subject to their own laws, un-interacting, and each reflecting the entire universe in a pre-established harmony (a historically important example of panpsychism). Monads are centers of force; substance is force, while space, matter, and motion are merely phenomenal.
>
> The ontological essence of a monad is its irreducible simplicity. Unlike atoms, monads possess no material or spatial character. They also differ from atoms by their complete mutual independence, so that interactions among monads are only apparent. Instead, by virtue of the principle of pre-established harmony, each monad follows a preprogrammed set of "instructions" peculiar to itself, so that a monad "knows" what to do at each moment. (These "instructions" may be seen as analogs of the scientific laws governing subatomic particles.) By virtue of these intrinsic instructions, each monad is like a little mirror of the universe. Monads need not be "small"; e.g., each human being constitutes a monad, in which case free will is problematic.